# Alternative to OLI simulation software

Tags: electrochemistry, aqueous-solution

I work with modeling a number of aqueous solutions, but mostly it boils down to single-component saline solutions. The industry standard for determining various saline solution quantities such as conductivity, activity, and density as a function of salinity and temperature is OLI.

OLI also provides capabilities that are way over the top for what I'm looking for (e.g. corrosion, scaling), and I'm wondering if an alternative exists that is less capable and hopefully less costly.

I have experience with writing and compiling software, so user-friendliness is not that important for me.

Comment: If all you are interested in are conductivity, density and activity coefficients, I would say you need lookup tables instead of a software package.  I don't know the details of the internal workings of OLI, but I would be willing to bet it is some look up table from a reference book for the kinds of values you are looking for. You may want to check the help file/documentation for OLI for such references.